# Javascript show specific array data from global array data with another case

Tags: javascript

I'm continuing with previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65486636/javascript-show-specific-array-data-from-global-array-data)

On this below code,

```js
var wantToShow = ['Football', 'Rugby', 'Tennis', 'Badminton', 'Fishing']; //without hiking
var objSport = ['Football', 'Rugby', 'Tennis', 'Badminton', 'Hiking', 'Fishing'];
var objSportIDLanguange = ['Sepakbola', 'Ragbi', 'Tenis', 'Bulu Tangkis', 'Mendaki', 'Memancing'];
var objTime = ['10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00', '19:00', '18:00'];

for(var i in objSport)
{
    if(wantToShow.indexOf(objSport[i]) > -1) {
      var newOption = $('<th class="th"><div class="name">'+objSport[i]+'</div><div class="time">'+objTime[i]+'</div></th>');
    $('.tblSport').append(newOption);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tblSport"></table>
```

Now I have another variable called `var objSportIDLanguange = ['Sepakbola', 'Ragbi', 'Tenis', 'Bulu Tangkis', 'Mendaki', 'Memancing']`

It's to translate from English to Indonesia.

So on below code I put some code:

```
var statusTranslate  = "Y";
for(var i in objSport)
{
    if(wantToShow.indexOf(objSport[i]) > -1) {
      if(statusTranslate = "Y")
      {
          //Here I need the var objSportIDLanguange value
      }
      else
      {
          var newOption = $('<th class="th"><div class="name">'+objSport[i]+'</div><div class="time">'+objTime[i]+'</div></th>');
      }
      $('.tblSport').append(newOption);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `statusTranslate == "Y" ? objSportIDLanguange[i] : objSport[i]` this will return `objSportIDLanguange` value if `Y` else other value then pass this to your div .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
var wantToShow = ['Football', 'Rugby', 'Tennis', 'Badminton', 'Fishing']; //without hiking
var objSport = ['Football', 'Rugby', 'Tennis', 'Badminton', 'Hiking', 'Fishing'];
var objSportIDLanguange = ['Sepakbola', 'Ragbi', 'Tenis', 'Bulu Tangkis', 'Mendaki', 'Memancing'];
var objTime = ['10:00', '12:00', '14:00', '16:00', '19:00', '18:00'];

var statusTranslate = "Y";
for (var i in objSport) {
  if (wantToShow.indexOf(objSport[i]) > -1) {
  //check if sttus transalte is y then use sprtlange else other
    var value = statusTranslate == "Y" ? objSportIDLanguange[i] : objSport[i]
//pass same
    var newOption = $('<th class="th"><div class="name">' + value + '</div><div class="time">' + objTime[i] + '</div></th>');

    $('.tblSport').append(newOption);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="tblSport"></table>
```

Comment: Hi, 1 question how about if I set like this `var objSportIDLanguange = ['Sepakbola', 'Ragbi', 'Tenis', 'Bulu Tangkis', 'Memancing'];` without `Mendaki`. I mean only value `var wantToShow` will be translate. Not in global array `objSport`

Comment: Please have a look on this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c2kgofp1/

Comment: Hi, wantToShow will be in english only ? because `objSportIDLanguange`  is in another language they will not match

Comment: Hi wantToShow can be English or Indonesia. The point is only translate with requirement `if (wantToShow.indexOf(objSport[i]) > -1)`

Comment: so if `statusTranslate` is `y` then `wantToShow` will be another language and if `n` then  `wantToShow` will be in english ? am i right ?

Comment: Yes, like that what I mean

Comment: I am still not sure if i understood or not what you are trying to say. But , check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/m9qs4ytc/) fiddle .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226549/discussion-between-hidayurie-dave-and-swati).